# Vectorize a numpy routine

Tags: python, numpy

I've got the following routine I've written that takes two arbitrary curves and warps the space between them so it fits between two straight lines. For the loop, it process it per column as `np.linspace` doesn't operate on vectors AFAIK. Is there way to get rid of this loop and hit the whole thing at once?

```
def warp(img, iris_curve, pupil_curve):
  height, width = img.shape[:2]
  iris_height = np.uint8(np.max(np.int8(iris_curve) - pupil_curve))
  out = np.zeros((iris_height, width))

  for r in range(0,width):
    map_theta = np.linspace(pupil_curve[r], iris_curve[r], iris_height)
    map_theta = np.uint8(np.rint(map_theta))
    out[:, r] = img[map_theta, r]

  return np.uint8(out)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you peek into the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.8.1/numpy/core/function_base.py#L91) of `np.linspace`, you can use that as a guide to vectorize your code. Your loop would then be replaced by something like:

```
steps = (iris_curve - pupil_curve) / iris_height
map_theta = np.arange(iris_height)[:, None] * steps + pupil_curve
map_theta = np.rint(map_theta).astype(np.uint8)
out = img[map_theta, np.arange(width)]
```

You may have to transpose the output, it's hard to debug this kind of code without an example.

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts looking at this code is that the for loop is unlikely to be the most significant thing hampering performace. There is an awful lot of copying of data around in this code (calling linspace creates a new array then this is copied back into the larger output array. casting to different types also involves copying data around). For example, can you not initiate your output as

```
np.empty((h,w),dtype=np.uint8)
```

Moreover do you really need to explicitly calculate all these values? Unless you reference all of them you might be better off just using the 2D linear interpolator from scipy.

If you really want to produce the output as-is I think you'll have to write something custom in Cython or similar.

Comment: Thanks, suggestion noted. I do need to reference all this data (it corrects the geometry of an image that is consequently processed afterwards), so perhaps Cython is the way.

Comment: OK so I proved what you said was right - I managed to rewrite the loop as a vector algorithm and it turns out the data copying is very slow. Any idea how to speed it up?